# JIRA How to get the resource params at getVelocityParameters function

Tags: jira, custom-fields

I have develop a custom field, the xml is:

```
<customfield-type key="mailru-select" name="An easily filled select list" class="ru.mail.plugins.ms.MailSelectCF">
<description>An easily filled select list.</description>
<resource type="velocity" name="view" location="templates/view-mailselect.vm"/>
<resource type="velocity" name="column-view" location="templates/view-mailselect.vm">
    <params key = "<strong>actionName</strong>" value="abcde">
</resource>
<resource type="velocity" name="xml" location="templates/view-mailselect.vm"/>
<resource type="velocity" name="edit" location="templates/edit-mailselect.vm"/>
```

The getVelocityParameters function is :

```
public Map<String, Object> getVelocityParameters(Issue issue,
    CustomField field, FieldLayoutItem fieldLayoutItem) {
 // how to get the actionName
Map<String, Object> params = super.getVelocityParameters(issue, field,
        fieldLayoutItem);
long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
Set<String> cfVals;
if (field.isGlobal()) {
    cfVals = msMgr.getValues(Consts.GROBAL_CF_PROJ, field.getId());
} else {
    if (issue == null || issue.getProjectObject() == null) {
        return params;
    }
    cfVals = msMgr.getValues(issue.getProjectObject().getKey(),
    field.getId());
}
params.put("selectVal", issue.getCustomFieldValue(field));
params.put("cfVals", cfVals);
return params;
```

}

How to get the actionName on function getVelocityParameters